# How to interpret this html page and where do I add meta tag

Tags: redirects, html, meta-tags

I'd like to redirect my webpage to another webpage. I used a template to develop the website and I couldn't read the code on this page. Could anyone tell me what does the code below means?

```
--- layout: archive title: "News" permalink: /news/ author_profile: true --- {% include base_path %} {% for post in site.news reversed %} {% include archive-single.html %} {% endfor %}
```

Here is the meta tag I plan to insert. Could anyone please tell me where in the above code could I insert the meta tag below?

`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://www.w3docs.com'" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To code you asked about is not html - I assume its part if some kind if framework and is its own scripting language/pseudo language.

```
--- layout: archive title: "News" permalink: /news/ author_profile: true --- 
{% include base_path %} 
{% for post in site.news reversed %} 
      {% include archive-single.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

The pseudocode appears to include other files / text, including gloopong through posts and displaying them. Without knowing the framework/language its not possible to be certain, but I would back up the existing page and replace everything with just the redirect meta tag you wrote and see if that works.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I will try that!